# I need to edit the attributes of four input types dynamically ( text - textarea - select - button )

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have Four controls each one takes the Data from an input parameter.

form-container-component

```
<div class="container col-md-9 mt-5">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <app-text-box
      [inputValue]="textBox"
      (textInputValue)="showData($event)"
    ></app-text-box>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <app-textarea
      [textarea]="textarea"
      (textareaValue)="showData($event)"
    ></app-textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <app-select-box
      [selectBox]="selectBox"
      (selectBoxValue)="showData($event)"
    ></app-select-box>
  </div>
  
  <app-button [button]="button" (buttonValue)="showData($event)"></app-button>
</div>
```

and these are the values assigned

```
 textBox = {
    fontColor: 'red',
    fontSize: '20',
    placeholder: 'name',
    name: 'input name',
    label: 'mohamed',
  };

  textarea = {
    fontColor: 'red',
    fontSize: '20',
    placeholder: 'name',
    name: 'input name',
    label: 'mohamed',
    cols: '50',
  };

  selectBox = {
    fontColor: 'red',
    fontSize: '20',
    name: 'input namee',
    label: 'mohamed',
  };

  button = {
    fontColor: 'red',
    fontSize: '20',
    name: 'input name',
    title: 'button',
    bgColor: 'green',
  };
```

there is a modal that shows a dynamic form. that update these attrs.
I can show them in the form but I need to update each one after changing its values.

this is the modal component where i build the dynamic form depending on the object key

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const inputDataObj = {} as any;
    for (const prop of Object.keys(this.InputObj)) {
      inputDataObj[prop] = new FormControl(this.InputObj[prop]);
      this.inputProps.push(prop);
    }
    this.form = new FormGroup(inputDataObj);
  }

  submit(){

  }
```

As you can see I got stuck on the submit function I need to select the Object that I need to update and pass it back to the component to show my changes.